# Box-Shadow issue?

Tags: html2canvas

I'm trying to make the CSS box-shadow working in html2canvas.
Searching in the last package (1.0.0 alpha 12) I could not find mention to boxShadow.
In fact I see that it works only when I use the old version 0.5.6
(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas-fixes@0.5.6/dist/html2canvas.js):
I'm confused because in that version there is a section for boxShadow rendering.
In following verions it seems disappeared.

And when I add the cdn link to 0.5.6 the box shadow is rendered only x (horizontal).
Might I know if s/one else had this problem? Thank you.